# VBA Excel Printing Word Doc - Not Printing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have code that is working fine on my own personal laptop, the code opens a Word document and prints it using the default printer.

The code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    ' Step 1
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    ' Hidden window!
    objWord.Visible = False
    ' Save the original printer, otherwise you will reset the system default!
    Dim previousPrinter As String


    ' Step 2
    Dim objDoc
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx")

    ' Step 3 -- in this case, print out the document without any prompts
    objDoc.PrintOut
    ' Restore the original printer
    objWord.ActivePrinter = previousPrinter

    ' Step 4
    objDoc.Close

    ' Step 5
    objWord.Quit
    MsgBox (objWord.ActivePrinter) 
End Sub
```

However, when I try this in the office, I get no error from the code however nothing gets sent to the printer. Is there anything that can cause this? it's a xerox printer (on a network), and it uses **follow print**

Comment: Sounds like you have an IT problem. Not a code problem.

Comment: Is this your complete printing code? I ask because you `Dim previousPrinter` but the variable is epmty when you use it `objWord.ActivePrinter = previousPrinter` because it was never set to any value. So it is the same as `objWord.ActivePrinter = ""`. Also your `MsgBox (objWord.ActivePrinter)` should not return anything (or an error) because Word was already quit `objWord.Quit` and therefore should not have an `ActivePrinter` anymore (at least this makes no sense). Actually how is the printer selected where the Word should print on? Actually there is nothing in your code about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forcing it to print on another printer then you'll need something like this:

```
previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter

For i = 0 To 15
   curNePrint = VBA.Format(i, "00")
   On Error Resume Next
      objWord.ActivePrinter = "\\ServerName\printername z111b on ne" & curNePrint & ":"
Next i

objWord.PrintOut Copies:=1
ObjWord.ActivePrinter = previousPrinter
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: If you use `On Error Resume Next` inside a loop then `On Error Goto 0` has to be inside the loop too. Otherwise the error reporting will stay off after the first loop even for the statements between `For i = 0 To 15` and `On Error Resume Next`. • Actually suppressing/hiding errors without showing any message at all is a very bad approach too. See [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) for a good explanation on how to use error handling properly.

Comment: This answer worked, but I don't know why? what is it doing differently? thanks so much